# MVC, entity framework, foreign key data not displayed creating new item

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using MVC4 and EF5 codefirst. Got a problem whereby when creating a new data record with reference to a row with a foreign key. Listing created entries everything looks fine:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.name)
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Action.name)
   ...
```

Creating a new record the reference fails to display the foreign content (names):

```
    ...
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.locationID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location.name)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.actionID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Action.name)
    ...
```

The foreign keys are correctly filled in the controller (see simplied example)

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Timerecord tm = new Timerecord();

        tm.currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        tm.locationID = 1;
        tm.actionID = 5;

        ViewData.Model = tm;
        return View();
    }
```

and the record is correctly created in the database. Just the names are not displayed on the view. Do I have to fetch the associated reocrd myselfs during the Create?

Comment: +1 That's what I've been doing, navigation properties work well after you insert the entity to database with just the foreignkeyid but I really would like to know if there's a workaround for this.

Comment: Could you show Timerecord class and view Create?

Comment: @sormii, that is what you get when you use foreign key properties to define navigation and collection properties. You can save the entity and then eager load the related entity using the `Include` extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any calls to `SaveChanges()` in your code. You need to invoke this in order for the foreign key properties to load the navigation properties. Either that or, like you said at the end of your question, load them explicitly.

Comment: Did the references myself:             
            tm.Location = dbLoc.Location.Find(tm.locationID);
            tm.Action = dbAct.Action.Find(tm.actionID);

Comment: Then you should update the code in your question to indicate that, as it should provide a different EF behavior and different results.